# jQuery flipswitch causing Backbone views reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I've been struggling with jQuery Mobile for days...jQuery was such a nice thing, but jQM has so many quirky things that is great for simple applications but hard to customize...

The current problem is how to disable jQM's flipswitch's anchor's behavior. My application stores a large amount of data in memory, so I do not want to reload them on every single page. I'm having a base view and switch "pages" by switching the subviews inside the base view.

Here's the sub view I'm having problem with:

```
<div data-role="main" class="option-main ui-content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="option-list">
    <li>
        <h1>Options</h1>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li><div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="Map-Mode">Play on Map</label><input type="checkbox" id="Map-Mode" data-role="flipswitch"></div></li>
    <li><div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="Battle-Request">Receive Battle Request</label><input type="checkbox" id="Battle-Request" data-role="flipswitch"></div></li>
    <li><div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="Always-Accept">Always Accept Battle Request</label><input type="checkbox" id="Always-Accept" data-role="flipswitch"></div></li>
    <li><div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="Vibration">Vibration</label><input type="checkbox" id="Vibration" data-role="flipswitch"></div></li>
    <li><div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="slider-1">Volume</label><input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="50" min="0" max="100"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Under jQM, the `<data-role="flipswitch">` attribute turns that input into a flipswitch.
The problem is the flipswitch is wrapped by an `<a>` tag by jQM default. Every time I click on the switch, the `<a>` tag is triggered and the view reloads itself. I tried the following to disable the tag:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
)
  .attr("href", null);
```

but it is not working.

The problem is definitely on the `<a>` tag. If I change it into a `<span>` in DevTool, everything works just fine. But the `<a>` is generated on runtime, so I cannot change it on my end.

Why would they use a `<a>` tag at such a place!? The "off" state is wrapped by an `<span>`, why they used a `<a>` for "on" state?

Is there any way to disable the behavior of `<a>`? I can definitely copy the generated HTML and replace my input,then change the `<a>` to `<span>`...but then what's the point of using jQM? Maybe I should just switch to Bootstrap 3...

**Edited:** **Solved:**

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    return false;
)
```

stopped behavior of `<a>` but did not entirely solve the problem. This will cancel the default click effect on the flipswitch.

Tried @dave 's solution,

```
$(".option-main ul li input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            $(this).flipswitch({
                create: function( event, ui ) { 
                    $('.ui-flipswitch-on').each(function() { 
                        $(this).replaceWith('<span class="' + 
                            $(this).attr('class') + 
                            '">' + 
                            $(this).html() + 
                        '</span>'); 

                    });

                }
            }, {defaults: true});
        });
```

Now all the a tags are cancelled, everything works well. Flipswitch is initialized dynamically. After these I also called `$(".parent-selector").create()` to force the flipswitchs trigger the "create" method. This last step is not necessary, depends on if your flipswitch is rendered correctly.

Comment: As a side note, unless you want to target Blackberry, I don't see a reason to use jqm when there're so many new lightweight frameworks. F7, Ratchet, etc.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the note. Yeah I'm new to mobile frameworks so I picked one that is relatively famous. I will try a lightweight frameworks. JQM has its limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that the `a` tag is generated at runtime.  Chances are, your function

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}).attr("href", null);
```

Is getting run before the a tag has been generated, so the event handler doesn't get bound to that element.  What you could try is to either use event delegation:

```
 $("body").on("click", "a", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
 });
```

If that doesn't work, and after looking into it I would actually attempt it this way first, use JQM 's event for the flipswitch to do it:

```
$( ".selector" ).flipswitch({
  create: function( event, ui ) { 
      $('.ui-flipswitch-on').on("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
      })
  }
});
```

All that being said, I believe JQM does that anyways - when you click on it in their examples, nothing in the url changes... so it is most likely an issue somewhere in YOUR code.  You may have to simply replace the a element with something else.  This seems to work:

```
$( ".selector" ).flipswitch({
  create: function( event, ui ) { 
    $('.ui-flipswitch-on').each(function() { 
       $(this).replaceWith('<div class="' + 
                          $(this).attr('class') + 
                          '">' + 
                          $(this).html() + 
                          '</div>'); 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've included your answer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pre-rendering markup option will allow you to override the behavior of JQM creating a  tag.

As an example the first flipswitch input tag in your html is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Map-Mode" data-role="flipswitch">
```

Render the page in a browser and use the resulting html. Convert the  tag to  and add data-enhanced="true" attribute to the  tag.

```
<div class="ui-flipswitch ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all">
  <span class="ui-flipswitch-on ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-inherit">On</span>
  <span class="ui-flipswitch-off">Off</span>
  <input id="Map-Mode" class="ui-flipswitch-input" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-enhanced="true" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```